# Selenium client-sided load test max request per second?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests, load-testing

I am using Selenium to perform client-sided testing of a specific browser on an AngularJS web application. I want perform a load test by sending many request from concurrent users. For example, 1k request in a second from x amount of users, 2k request, etc.

There is no formal documentation on this topic. Has anyone done this before? Is there an (expected) maximum amount of request Selenium can perform, I know it would be dependant on hardware. I also know there exist tools such as Jmeter, but those do not run client-side JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to test client-side or server side? If it is client-side, why do you need to test a large load? If you want to test server side, you need JMeter. If you want to run multiple browser windows, just create multiple instances of webdriver.

Comment: @Buaban As already stated, I want to test a large load on client-sided. Jmeter is server-side so it doesnt execute the JavaScript, and I want to see the performance of the AngularJS+some other JavaScript code I have running on the client side. More specifically, I have a P2P web app, that I want to test it on, which has client-side JavaScript functions.

Comment: I see, it's P2P. You should put it in your question. How do you generate 1k requests? Is it a functionality of your app? Or do you want to have 1k of web browsers?

Comment: I've just found this tutorial about [JMeter WebDriver](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler). It would help.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't run client-side JavaScript but in order to simulate 2k concurrent users you simply don't need to run it. If JavaScript is generating some network traffic - your will be able to mimic it using normal JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers. Client-side performance, i.e. script(s) execution timeline should be tested separately using [JavaScript Profilers](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/) and/or tools like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)

Also be aware that Selenium can be integrated with JMeter via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) plugin.

Alternatively you can consider [LoadRunner TruClient](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/TruClient-in-the-world-of-Load-Testing/ba-p/233363), however both approaches which kick off real browsers (no mater full or headless) will be very resources intensive.